# PHP Adding stylesheets to header

Tags: php, html, class, stylesheet, magic-methods

Is there a way to add stylesheets to the header after including the header file? Say we have this code:

```
class content {
    public $stylesheets = array();

    public function addStylesheets($stylesheets)
    {
        if(!empty($stylesheets))
        {
            if(!is_array($stylesheets))
                $stylesheets = array($stylesheets);

            $this->stylesheets = array_merge($this->stylesheets, $stylesheets);
        }
    }

    public function getStylesheets()
    {
        $response = '';

        foreach($this->stylesheets as $stylesheet)
            $response .= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $stylesheet . '" />' . Chr(13);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

And this header:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
    <?php
        print($content->getStylesheets());
    ?>
</head>

<bod...
```

And then later in the file I want to add stylesheets like this:

```
$content->addStylesheets(array('home.css', 'slider.css'));
```

Can someone give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: A good practice is to separate html from php, you can use templates engine like smarty or twig. But if you don't want to use it then generate your html at the end, first execute your php code and then render html. So first `if (something) { $content->addStyleSheet($style)} ... (some other code) ... echo $myTemplate;` where $myTemplate contains your site

Answer (score 0):

The final html code is always generated at the end. Here is an example how to proceed with pure php/html. Your index.php could look something like this:

```
<?php

// ...

// Define the stylesheets to use
$content = new content();
$content->addStylesheets(array('home.css', 'slider.css'));

// ...

// Print template at the end
ob_start();
include 'your_html_template.php';
print ob_get_clean();
```

The `your_html_template.php` is your template file as shown in the question.

---

You can **define variables** before executing the template to have a more clear **separation of php code and html**. Then the index.php could look like this:

```
<?php

// ...

// Define the stylesheets to use
$content = new content();
$content->addStylesheets(array('home.css', 'slider.css'));
$htmlStyleHeaderTags = $content->getStylesheets();  // Define variable with html header tags

// ...

// Print template at the end
ob_start();
include 'your_html_template.php';
print ob_get_clean();
```

And then you can use the variable `$htmlStyleHeaderTags` in your template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
    <?php print $htmlStyleHeaderTags; ?>
</head>

<bod...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @szapio already sad, it makes more sense to build the HTML at the very end.

Anyway, a "dirty" solution would be to hack your DOM with jQuery by putting the 
following before the `</body>`-tag (having jQuery included in the `<head>`):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />');
});
</script>
```

You really shouldn't consider doing this, because the CSS file will be loaded after everything else, meaning you will see the unstyled elements as long as the CSS file is not loaded yet…