# why the font awesome doesn't work in this html code?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I want to use font awesome in my html code. The following is my code. But it doesn't get applied.. I've saved the font awesome dir within my project folder as well..

```
<?php
include '../config/sessionhandling.php';
//print_r($_SESSION['userrow']);
$role_id=$userrow['role_id'];

include '../config/dbconnection.php';
include '../model/user_model.php';

$obu=new user_model();
$resultu=$obu->viewUsers();
$nou=$resultu->rowCount();

$resultud=$obu->viewUsersDe("Deactive");
$noud=$resultud->rowCount();
$noua=$nou-$noud;    

$to=date('Y-m-d');
$resultday=$obu->viewLogPerDay($to);
$noday=$resultud->rowCount();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Faculty Management System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
              href="../css/layout.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
              href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!--        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../fontawesome-free-5.12.0-web/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
           <?php
           include '../templates/header.php'; ?>
            <?php 
            include '../templates/userrole.php'; ?>
            <div id="navigation">
                <div>
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="active">
           <a href="../view/dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                &nbsp;</div>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul style="list-style: none">

                                <li> 
                                <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
                                <a href="user.php">User</a></li>

                                <li> 
<!--                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon"></i>-->
                                <a href="item.php">Faculty</a></li>

                                <li>
<!--                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></i>-->
                                <a href="stock.php">Department</a></li>

                                <?php //} 
                                //if ($role_id!=3) { ?>
                                <li>
<!--                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i>-->
                                <a href="payment.php">Course</a></li>

                                <li>
                                <?php //} ?>
<!--                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></i>-->
                                <a href="purchaseorder.php">Appointment</a></li>

                                <li>
                               <i class="fas fa-bells"></i>
                                <a href="order.php">Notification</a></li>

                                <?php //if($role_id==1 || $role_id==2) { ?>
                                <li> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>
                                <a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>

                                <li> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i>
                                <a href="report.php">Report</a></li>

                                <?php //if($role_id==1) { ?>
                                <li> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i>
                                <a href="backup.php">Backup</a></li>
                                <?php //} ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php if($role_id==1){ ?>
                            <div class="col-md-4">    <!--Grid technique is used -->
                                <div class="panel panel-success">  <!-- panel-success gives green colour to the panel-->
                                <div class="panel panel-heading">
                                    User and Login

                                </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <p>No.of Users:<span class="badge"><?php echo $nou; ?></span></p>
                                        <p>Active Users:<span class="badge"><?php echo $noua; ?></span></p>
                                        <p>Deactive Users:<span class="badge"><?php echo $noud; ?></span></p>
                                        <p>No. of Login(<?php echo date ('Y-m-d');?>): <span class="badge"><?php echo $noday; ?></span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
               </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>             
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php  include '../templates/footer.php'; ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to display some of the icons in my dashboard and is there a better way to accomplish this? Please help me to sort this out.....Or is there a better way to use font awesome??

Comment: Did you confirm your fontawesome path ?
try try <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Check your path. Go to your website and View page source. Click the link to your font awesome and see if it opens up. If it shows error or 404, means your path is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a type attribute to your link element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fontawesome-free-5.12.0-web/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and check your font awesome css link like this

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CDN:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, font awesome has a cdn you should be using as part of your account. That way you don't have to manage its updates.

Second, review this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500848/php-adding-stylesheets-to-header). This is a better way to include files in a site for your users. Remember, PHP is a server-side rendering language. When you are including links directly in your head, it is up to the user (the browser) to render your file which essentially slows down the page-load. This isn't a big deal for a single file, but if you're doing this with multiple files you're unnecessarily slowing down your site. PHP is efficient at running scripts on the server and you're maximizing the usage you pay for in your server.

The crux of that thread teaches you to:

1. Define your stylesheet and it's variable(s)
2. Lookup how to use output buffering to get it to load correctly

If you're using wordpress, it has a custom "hook" called "enqueue" that you can include in functions.php that will achieve the same effect. [FAQ](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) on Wordpress wp_enqueue_style() functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet. Changed the fas fa-github to fab fa-github.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">



<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Henrique Borges</h1>
  <p class="lead">Programador experiente e Web Designer.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <i class="fab fa-github btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="#" role="button"> Github</i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDN link in the head tag :

```
<link type='text/css'  href='the font link' >
```

Note : You should attach the config files of your framework or the CDN link in your html in every project . Don't forget.